# Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be disjoint cycles. Prove for every positive integer n, $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be disjoint cycles. Say $\alpha = (a_1a_2...a_s)$, $\beta=(b_1b_2...b_r)$.

Prove for every positive integer n, $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$

My proof is as follows: Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint, in the product $(\alpha\beta)$, $\alpha$ only moves $a's$ while $\beta$ only moves $b's$.  In the product $(\alpha\beta)^n$, $\alpha$ moves the $a's$ $n$ times while $\beta$ moves $b's$ $n$ times. Therefore, $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$

Is this proof correct/sufficient?

Comment: I guess. You could just note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute, which would imply the result.

Comment: But how does your conclusion follow from your observation? I would first prove commutativity: $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$.

Comment: I know they commute, but I can't see how if $(\alpha\beta)=(\beta\alpha)$, it would imply the result. Please explain.

Comment: In any group if $g,h$ commute then $(gh)^n=g^nh^n$. Have you tried proving this? (Also, your response to my comment did not ping me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is *correct*, but it feels a bit hand-wavy - that is, it's hoping that the reader is going to follow exactly what you're saying; you can formalize your argument by splitting the set on which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ act into the a's and the b's, as you put it, and then noticing that, defining these as functions just on those sets, they don't interact.

However, a much easier way would be to prove that $\alpha\beta =\beta\alpha$ - that the elements commute. You'll likely have to do a similar job of splitting into a's and b's, but you don't have to make any arguments about why this must hold for *powers* of the function - you just need that they commute, and it follows that $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$.

Comment: I can't see how stating that they commute will make it different. Please explain. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "make it different"? Clearly, $(ab)^2=abab$ and if they commute, exchanging the middle terms gives $abab=aabb=a^2b^2$ - higher powers are similarly simple to complete the proof for.

If you mean how it will make the proof different, I suppose the proof would be largely the same as you have it now (i.e. all the a's are fixed points of $\beta$ and vice versa, so they don't affect each other), but just as a matter of clarity, it would be easier for a reader to understand the single case $ab=ba$ than all powers; it also uses group-theory in a deeper way when you do this.